# Taking care of Birds: Unwanted species scaring away a less common one from a birdhouse

Tags: ornithology, invasive-species

Near my house, I have set up a birdhouse, which has become home to a pair of Oriental Magpie Robins. They are not a common species in Delhi, India, and are generally shy of human interaction and avian conflict (territory disputes with other species):

However, the birdhouse is constantly visited by a pair of Common Myna. This bird is notorious for being an invasive species and had chased away a pair of Oriental Magpie Robins in the past.

Is there some way for me to get rid of the Mynas without scaring away the Oriental Magpie Robins? The bird is a real menace and I'm afraid it'll push away the Oriental Magpie Robin and other species of smaller birds that visit my locality. It is already considered an invasive species in Australia and South Africa. I don't want to kill the Myna, and trapping is out of the question as well. I just want to scare it off or restrict access to the birdhouse. Is there some way to make the birdhouse and surrounding area more appealing to the Oriental Magpie Robins?

[image: This is what they look like. The darker one is male.]
^Oriental Magpie Robin. The darker one is male, the lighter one is female.

[image: Myna.]

^Myna.

Update: The Mynas seem to be guarding the bird house from a distance, since I have been shooing them away. The Oriental Magpie Robin hasn't showed up since.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to foil Mynas is to use an [Anti Myna baffle](http://www.livingsmartqld.com.au/modules/biodiversity/PDFS/BirdsAustraliaFactsheet9-Nest-box-technical-information.pdf) over the nest box. Since Myna always fly directly into the nest box hole, this baffle prevents that while allowing other species to enter the box.